# A function on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ written as a combinations of Schwartz functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this exercise:

Let $\psi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be such that $\psi(0)=0$. Prove that there are functions $\rho_j \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $j=1,2,...,n$, such that $$\psi(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\rho_j(x)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have no idea how to start it. Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $x\in\mathbb R^n$, define $f_x\colon t\mapsto \psi\left(tx\right)$, $t\in \mathbb R$. Then $\psi(x)=f_x(1)-f_x(0)=\int_0^1f_x'(s)\mathrm ds$. The computation of the derivative will give the expression for the functions $\rho_j$. Then it will remain to check that these functions belong to the Schwartz space.

Comment: So, computing the derivative I got $f'_x(s)=\nabla\psi\cdot x$ and then the functions $\rho_j$ would be $\int_0^1\psi_{x_j}(sx)ds$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$

Comment: In order to show that these $\rho_j$'s belong to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ I can use the fact that $\psi$ is a Schwartz function and then it's derivatives satisfy the seminorm condition right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to use this.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!